# Error calling SetAccessor when binding C++ functions to V8

Tags: javascript, c++, v8

I'm following the [Embedder's Guide](https://developers.google.com/v8/embed) for V8 in order to call C++ from JavaScript. I am encountering an error with setting accessors. Specifically, the following code does not compile for me under the current version of V8 with VS2015.

```
point_templ.SetAccessor(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "x"), GetPointX, SetPointX);
```

I can get it to work mostly as expected if I change it to:

```
point_templ->SetAccessor(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "x"), GetPointX);
```

I just cannot get it to accept the setter function. I get an error stating "no instance of overloaded function "v8::ObjectTemplate::SetAccessor" matches the argument list". For the record, I have not modified the example functions from what they are in the guide. They are the following (copied from the guide):

```
void GetPointX(Local<String> property, const PropertyCallbackInfo<Value>& info)
{
   Local<Object> self = info.Holder();
   Local<External> wrap = Local<External>::Cast(self->GetInternalField(0));
   void* ptr = wrap->Value();
   int value = static_cast<Point*>(ptr)->x_;
   info.GetReturnValue().Set(value);
}

void SetPointX(Local<String> property, Local<Value> value, const PropertyCallbackInfo<Value>& info)
{
   Local<Object> self = info.Holder();
   Local<External> wrap = Local<External>::Cast(self->GetInternalField(0));
   void* ptr = wrap->Value();
   static_cast<Point*>(ptr)->x_ = value->Int32Value();
}
```

Is the required function signature for the setter different from what it is in the guide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll leave this here for anyone else trying to follow the guide: the function signature for the setter *is* wrong, but if you skim too quickly you'll miss it. The guide has the setter as:

```
void SetPointX(Local<String> property, Local<Value> value, const PropertyCallbackInfo<Value>& info)
```

The function signature should *actually* be:

```
 void SetPointX(Local<String> property, Local<Value> value, const PropertyCallbackInfo<void>& info)
```

Note that it's **void** rather than **Value** (and that it is point_templ->SetAccessor(), not point_templ.SetAccessor()).

Comment: I’ve updated our guide: https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Embedder's-Guide Diff: https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Embedder's-Guide/_compare/c99e4713801a2a7a3ffada11fbcf616790b95538...8a127d10ac78c08383ec1e4d1b590505487e9c83